# JSonParser turning up nulls

Tags: java, jsonparser

I am traversing a Json file and seem to only get nulls.  As you can see I'm trying to access them with index.  Also, my integer is funny because it doesn't like when I use Integer.parseInt from the json value.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Kelly",
      "age": 50,
      "sex": "f",
      "illness": "Allergies"
    },
    {
      "name": "Josh",
      "age": 40,
      "sex": "m",
      "illness": "Sleep Apnea"
    },
    {
      "name": "Brad",
      "age": 20,
      "sex": "m",
      "illness": "Heart Disease"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Java:**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;


public class FileLoader {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        int count = 0;

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                "Consumers.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("people");

            if(array.size() > 0) {
                while (count < array.size()) {
```

**Answer edit**

```
JSONObject people = (JSONObject) array.get(count);
                    String name = (String) people .get("name");
                    int age = (Integer) people .get("age");
                    String sex = (String) people .get("sex");
                    String illness = (String) people .get("illness");
```

**finish edit**

```
                    JSONObject people = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(count);
                    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
                    int age = (Integer) jsonObject.get("age");
                    String sex = (String) jsonObject.get("sex");
                    String illness = (String) jsonObject.get("illness");


                    System.out.println("\nPeople List " + count + ": ");
                    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                    System.out.println("Age: " + age);
                    System.out.println("Sex: " + sex);
                    System.out.println("Illness: " + illness);
                    count++;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I only need to read in the file but I am having trouble reading the nested array.  All the values come back null.  I have this built as a maven project.

Comment: You assigned people to the index off the top level JSON object, not the array.

Comment: @JimW I must not be building my json object right then.  I should assign the top object as people is an array with information in it I'm trying to get to.

Comment: No you are, just change JSONObject people = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(count); to JSONObject people = (JSONObject) array.get(count); You're checking the size of the array, but setting people to the index of jsonObject

Comment: @JimW can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the issue:

```
JSONObject people = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(count);
```

jsonObject isn't the array of people, it's the top level JSON Object. Since that top level of the object has only one key ("people") the calls to get(0), get(1), ... all return null.

Here is the correct line using array instead of jsonObject:

```
JSONObject people = (JSONObject) array.get(count);
```